# Show that $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$, given the axiomatic definition of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

If instead of constructing $\mathbb{R}$ from $\mathbb{Q}$, we define it axiomatically, as a complete ordered field, how would one show that $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Here's a sketch of the idea to do it.  Map $\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb R$ by $1\mapsto 1$.  Then $n\mapsto n\cdot 1$.  This way we find a copy of $\Bbb Z$ inside $\Bbb R$.  Since $\Bbb R$ is a field, it follows that $\Bbb Q$ must also be in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't quite show that. But you can show something close enough.

Because if you define $\Bbb R$ axiomatically, and you claim that $\Bbb R$ is a model of these axioms, then there is no guarantee that the model will coincide with $\Bbb Q$ in any reasonable way.

But you can show that there is an embedding of $\Bbb Q$ into $\Bbb R$ which preserves the ordered field structure (and the image of the embedding is indeed dense in $\Bbb R$).

> The point is that $\Bbb Q\subseteq\Bbb R$ is a specific claim about sets, or structures for some language which may or may not be true given the specific sets chosen to interpret these two fields.
>
> But "*There is an embedding from $\Bbb Q$, into $\Bbb R$*" (however you defined these objects) is a general and abstract statement which is what you really want to prove. What is worth mentioning, as egreg points in the comment, is that such embedding is in fact *unique*.

To see there is an embedding, proceed by induction using the constants $0,1$ to show that all the natural numbers can be "identified" in $\Bbb R$. Proceed to conclude from the existence of additive inverses that the "identification" extends into $\Bbb Z$. Finally, from multiplicative inverses for non-zero numbers extend this identification to $\Bbb Q$ itself.

We need to show that it preserves addition and multiplication, which can be shown by similar inductions. And the order is preserved by similar arguments of building this from the naturals to the rationals.

Comment: Once you see that $\mathbb{R}$ has characteristic $0$, there is a *unique* ring monomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{R}$, which uniquely extends to a monomorphism $\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{R}$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ can be ordered (as a field) in a unique way, this monomorphism preserves the ordering. Of course you can choose to ignore the basic theory of rings. `;-)`

Comment: Yes, but this requires a wee bit understanding in algebra, and this answer doesn't quite assume it (and it fits the tags chosen by the OP, by the way). But the point is that $\Bbb{Q\to R}$ is not the same as $\Bbb{Q\subseteq R}$ as a mathematical statement.

Comment: Well, *what* is $\mathbb{Q}$? `:-)` I know at least two different constructions. And I could decide that the “true” $\mathbb{Q}$ is the set built this way.

Comment: I know several other *meanings* of what it means to be $\Bbb Q$ (e.g. $\omega^{<\omega}$ can be considered as $\Bbb Q$ in some contexts). But the point is that $\Bbb{Q\subseteq R}$ is a statement about sets, or substructure if you will, whereas $\Bbb{Q\to R}$ is a statement about fields and homomorphisms thereof. It is probably a good idea to point out the difference, which is often ignored in analysis, between different sets, so for example $\Bbb{R\nsubseteq R^2}$ in the "usual" way of constructing $\Bbb R$. Instead there are several, all very natural, identifications of subsets of $\Bbb R^2$

Comment: I agree completely, of course. However, in this particular case there's a small (or big, if you prefer) difference: there is a *unique* copy of $\mathbb{Q}$ (however you build it) in $\mathbb{R}$ (however you build it) and I believe this is worth mentioning.

Comment: Great suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Does this amount to saying that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @moni94: It amounts to saying that there is a copy of $\Bbb Q$ which is a subfield of $\Bbb R$. What we can do is say that this copy is the actual $\Bbb Q$, and not whatever we had previously. Then your statement about it being a subfield is true.

Comment: Just one more thing: isn't $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$ a statement about the sets underlying the fields as opposed to the fields themselves? I just want to show that if $q$ is a rational number, then $q$ is a real number and am not concerned with the relations of the elements of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @moni94: In this context it is a statement about structures, namely you want to say that $(\Bbb Q,0,1,+,\cdot)$ is a substructure of $(\Bbb R,0,1,+,\cdot)$. Suppose that the elements of $\Bbb Q$ were actually interpreted as irrational numbers in $\Bbb R$, it would be weird, but certainly it's possible. You want to ask about it being a subfield, which in this case amounts to being a substructure.

Answer (score 5):

Well, $1 \in \mathbb{R}$, and it's closed under addition, so $1+1\in \mathbb{R}$. By induction (using the orderness to ensure that we get new elements at each step), $\mathbb{N}\subset \mathbb{R}$. Additive inverses are also present, so $\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{R}$. Now the field of fractions of a ring is the smallest field which contains that ring. And $\mathbb{Q}$ is the field of fractions for $\mathbb{Z}$. And $\mathbb{R}$ is a field containing $\mathbb{Z}$. So $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

1. $1\in\mathbb{R}$
2. $n=\underbrace{1+1+...+1}_{\mbox{n - times}}\in\mathbb{R}$
3. $-n\in\mathbb{R}$
4. $\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{R}$
5. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is a field and $\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{R}$ therefore $\frac{p}{q}\in \mathbb{R}$ for all $p\in \mathbb{Z} \wedge q\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$ thus $\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{R}$